# How to get the upload file with other inputs in play2?

Tags: forms, file-upload, playframework-2.0

In html, a form with multipart data:

```
<form action="@routes.Files.upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="groupId" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tagId" value="2" />
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="upload it"/>
</form>
```

How to write the action `Files upload`?

I know how to get a uploaded file:

```
request.body.file("file") map {
    filepart => filepart.ref.moveTo(newFile);
}
```

And how to get submitted inputs:

```
Form(tuple("groupId" -> text, "tagId" -> text)).bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => ...,
    params => ....
)
```

But how to combine them together?

I don't find a suitable type for `file` can be used in `Form(tuple(...))`, and neither a way to get input value in `request.body`.

Answer (score 27):

This answer is for Java, but you should be able to adapt it to Scala fairly easily.

What you need to do is define a Model for all the fields in your form *except* the file. Then use the file-upload API as normal to retrieve the file.

For example, this is what I did:

**The Form** (in upload.scala.html):

```
@form(action = routes.UploadResourceController.doUpload(), 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {

    @inputText(uploadForm("lang"))
    @inputText(uploadForm("country"))
    @inputFile(uploadForm("resourceFile"))

    <p>
        <input type="submit">
    </p>
}
```

**The Model** (models/UploadResource.java):

```
public class UploadResource {
    @Required
    public String lang;

    @Required
    public String country;

    /* notice a field for the file is missing */
}
```

**The Controller** (controllers/UploadResourceController.java):

```
public static Result doUpload() {
    Form<UploadResource> filledForm = uploadForm.bindFromRequest();

    if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(views.html.upload.render(filledForm));
    } else {
        UploadResource resource = filledForm.get();
        MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        FilePart resourceFile = body.getFile("resourceFile");

        /* Check resourceFile for null, then extract the File object and process it */
     }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: What if you want to store the location of file in the model? Otherwise, how will you know where the file is located after you process it? I guess I'm missing what the "file-upload API" is - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html ?

Comment: @SkylarSaveland - this code just lets you get the form data and the file. Once you have the file (the resourceFile in my example), you can move it to wherever you want to store it, and update your model with the location and filename.

Answer (score 13):

An example in Scala where the form field is required:

**Model:**

```
case class Specs (userid: String)
```

**Controller:**

```
object Upload extends Controller {
   val uploadForm = Form(
         mapping(
               "userid" -> nonEmptyText
         )(Specs.apply)(Specs.unapply)
   )
   def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
      val sp : Option[Specs] = uploadForm.bindFromRequest().fold (
            errFrm => None,
            spec => Some(spec)
      )
      request.body.file("file").map { f =>
         sp.map { spec =>
            val filePath = ... // incorporate userid
            // XXX: file read to memory b4 writing to disk. bad for large files
            f.ref.moveTo(new File(filePath), replace=true)
            Ok("File uploaded")
         }.getOrElse{
            BadRequest("Form binding error.")
         }
      }.getOrElse {
         BadRequest("File not attached.")
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another example how to do this can be this:

**Model:**

```
case class Specs(userId: String)
```

**Controller**

```
def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request => 
   uploadForm.bindFromRequest().fold(
   hasErrors => Ok(ourFormHTML(hasErrors),
   specs => {
      request.body.file("inputFileFieldName") match {
        case Some(file) => {
          import java.io.File
          val filename = file.filename
          val contetType = file.contentType
          file.ref.moveTo(new File(Play.application().path().getAbsolutePath + file.filename))
          Ok("congratz you did it")
        }
        case _ => Ok(ourHTML if we dont send file but want the form anyway)
      }
   }


 )
```

Dont forget to name the file, because you might end up wondering what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I was uploading a file using angular, with other form parameters. I created mine as below and it works.

**Angular Function**

```
Upload.upload({
    url: '/api/upload',
    method:'POST',
    data: {
        "file": user.profilePic, //file object
        "username": user.username

    }
}).then(function (resp) {
    //console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);

}, function (resp) {
    console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
}, function (evt) {
    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
    //console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
});
```

**Play 2.1 Controller**

```
/**
*
*Upload user profile 
**/
public static Result upload() {
    Logger.info("Uploading images##");
    Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart profile = body.getFile("file");
    if (profile != null) {
        File file = profile.getFile();

        //upload file to a directory
        //todo

        //get the username from form
          Map<String,String[]> dataPart = request().body().asMultipartFormData().asFormUrlEncoded();
          String username = dataPart.get("username")[0];

          //save/update the details with ebean

        return ok("File uploaded");
    } else {

        return status(400, "Missing file");
    }
}
```