# Playframework 2.2 Form bind from request with file

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

in Playframework 2.2, it is possible to bind an entity from request like so:

```
Form<EntityA> form = form.bindFromRequest();
EntityA entity = filledForm.get();
```

It seem to work for String values but it doesn't seem to work when I have a file in the entity and using the  @inputFile notation.

I can read the file via multipart form data as such:

```
MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
FilePart picture = body.getFile("uploadedFile");
```

But that is not elegant because I need to read the file via multipart form data and the other fields via the bindFromRequest.

I would like to do something like this:

```
Form<EntityA> form = form.bindFromRequest();
EntityA entity = filledForm.get();
File file = entity.uploadedFile;
```

but only null gets returned when the field is a file.

How do we upload a file into a form and get it directly from the binded form and not the multipart form data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your form contains an entity AND a file, you could solve it using this approach:  [How to get the upload file with other inputs in play2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452375/how-to-get-the-upload-file-with-other-inputs-in-play2#9587052)

If you can manipulate the POST methid, just don't use @inputFile for the entity. Otherwise, if what you want to bind is the @inputFile itself, you will need to use any marshalling/unmarshalling method.